# git fixup: get hash of original commit

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rebase

How does `git rebase -i --autosquash` know the original commit associated with a fixup? It seems the only "metadata" that `git commit --fixup` creates is the log message ("fixup!" + original message). The original commit hash is not stored anywhere in the fixup commit (at least, not that I can tell from `git show --raw`).

So given the fixup commit, how can I find the original commit being fixed?

I'm asking because `git rebase` *still* wants you to type a commit hash, even if it should be implied from fixup that I want `<original-hash>^`; maybe an alias is in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---autosquash) :

> `--autosquash`
> `--no-autosquash`
>
> When the commit log message begins with "squash! …​" (or "fixup! …​"), and there is already a commit in the todo list that matches the same ..., automatically modify the todo list of rebase -i so that the commit marked for squashing comes right after the commit to be modified, and change the action of the moved commit from `pick` to `squash` (or `fixup`).
>
> *[emphasis mine : ]*
> **A commit matches the ... if the commit subject matches, or if the ... refers to the commit’s hash**.
>
> As a fall-back, partial matches of the commit subject work, too. The recommended way to create fixup/squash commits is by using the `--fixup`/`--squash` options of git-commit[1].

note that "commit subject" means "the first line of the commit message" -- not "the complete commit mesage".